# undefined value for nodejs getter

Tags: node.js, getter

Trying to use getter in nodejs, but was getting undefined for it. What's the right way to declare it?

login.js

```js
let authorizedAxios;

const login = async () => {
  // get JWT token, then create a new axios to be used by app
  authorizedAxios = 5;
};

const http2 = () => authorizedAxios;

module.exports = {
  login,
  http2,
  get http() {
    return authorizedAxios;
  }
};
```

index.js

```js
const { login, http, http2 } = require("./login");

const test = async () => {
  await login();
  console.log("==== after");
  console.log("http", http);   // undefined
  console.log("http2", http2());  // 5
};

test();
```

Playground
[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/node-playground-forked-5d09pj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: This is expected behaviour. The getter is called when you call `require`. You can check it by adding console.log to the getter code. I would suggest to embrace async nature of your code and export a Promise or a promise returning function and do not try to hide it.

Comment: Or if your current node version supports es modules you can export variable `export let authorizedAxios` then you'd have this value at the moment of accessing

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you can add your first comment as reply, will mark it as answer

Comment: @YuryTarabanko the `export let` seems to give `undefined` as well, could it be due to the re-assignment to the variable break the reference. see updated playground code.

Comment: `export let` should work. https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-haslett-jkfs16?file=/index.js If you use babel for transpilation the access pattern for `import {a} from pkg` would look like `(void 0, pkg_exports.a)` to capture the dynamic nature.